# MySQL PHP Table Update / POST not working

Tags: php, mysql, post, get, edit

I have been working on a to do list which enables a person with admin rights to edit / update multiple percentages for all employees within a company from a form. The data that get sent could be anywhere between 50-200 entries and updated all at once.

The problem I have been facing is that the form and page works perfectly fine on my XAMPP local machine and runs through the motions of the update, however, as soon as I upload it to a live FTP, it doesn't. On the live server when I click on the submit button it loads and refreshes the page, but none of the values are updated and it doesn't redirect to the correct page (in fact it stays on the same page).

My PHP is a bit rusty and the solution might be simple, but for the life of me I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Here is my code and any constructive criticism in this regard will be highly appreciated.

```
<strong>Update Bulk To Do List</strong><br><br>

<?php 
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="kpi"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name ORDER BY country, person, type, lpad(jobnr, 100, 0)";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Count table rows 
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
?>




<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class='responsive'>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<tr> 
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<col width=3%>
<col width=5%>
<col width=3%>
<col width=15%>
<col width=35%>
<col width=15%>
<col width=18%>

<tr style='color: #fff; border-top: #d2d8db solid 2px; border-bottom: #d2d8db solid 2px'>
<td id='blue' bgcolor='#39a8f9' align="left" ><strong>ID</strong></td>
<td id='blue' bgcolor='#39a8f9' align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
<td id='blue' bgcolor='#39a8f9' align="center"><strong>No.</strong></td>
<td id='blue' bgcolor='#39a8f9' align="center"><strong>Brief</strong></td>
<td id='blue' bgcolor='#39a8f9' align="center"><strong>Detail</strong></td>
<td id='blue' bgcolor='#39a8f9' align="center"><strong>Type</strong></td>
<td id='blue' bgcolor='#39a8f9' align="center"><strong>%</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
<tr>
<td align="left" id='hovereff' style='border-bottom: #d2d8db solid 1px!important;'><?php $id[]=$rows['id']; ?><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor='#2c3e6c' id='hovereff' style='border-bottom: #d2d8db solid 1px!important;'><?php echo $rows['person']; ?><input type='hidden' id='person' name='person[]' value="<?php echo $rows['person']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor='#2c3e6c' id='hovereff' style='border-bottom: #d2d8db solid 1px!important;'><?php echo $rows['jobnr']; ?><input type='hidden' id='jobnr' name='jobnr[]' value="<?php echo $rows['jobnr']; ?>"></td>
<td align="left" bgcolor='#2c3e6c' id='hovereff' style='border-bottom: #d2d8db solid 1px!important;'><?php echo $rows['brief']; ?><input type='hidden' id='brief' name='brief[]' value="<?php echo $rows['brief']; ?>"></td>
<td align="left" bgcolor='#2c3e6c' id='hovereff' style='border-bottom: #d2d8db solid 1px!important;'><?php echo $rows['detail']; ?><input type='hidden' id='detail' name='detail[]' value="<?php echo $rows['detail']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor='#2c3e6c' id='hovereff' style='border-bottom: #d2d8db solid 1px!important;'><?php echo $rows['type']; ?><input type='hidden' id='type' name='type[]' value="<?php echo $rows['type']; ?>"></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor='#2c3e6c' id='hovereff' style='border-bottom: #d2d8db solid 1px!important;'>
<input name="overall_result[]" type="text" id="overall_result" value="<?php echo $rows['overall_result']; ?>">
<input type='hidden' id='expectation' name='expectation[]' value="<?php echo $rows['expectation']; ?>">
<input type='hidden' id='comments' name='comments[]' value="<?php echo $rows['comments']; ?>">
<input type='hidden' id='status' name='status[]' value="<?php echo $rows['status']; ?>">
<input type='hidden' id='country' name='country[]' value="<?php echo $rows['country']; ?>">
<input type='hidden' id='week' name='week[]' value="<?php date('d/m/Y', strtotime("Next Friday"))?>">


</td>
</tr>
<?php
}
?>
<tr>
<td colspan="7" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" class="upbutton" value="Update List"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</form>
</table>
<?php
// Check if button name "submit" is active, do this 
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$person=$_POST['person'];
$jobnr=$_POST['jobnr'];
$brief=$_POST['brief'];
$detail=$_POST['detail'];
$overall_result=$_POST['overall_result'];
$comments=$_POST['comments'];
$status=$_POST['status'];
$country=$_POST['country'];
$week=$_POST['week'];
$expectation=$_POST['expectation'];
$type=$_POST['type'];


for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$sql1="UPDATE $tbl_name SET person='$person[$i]', jobnr='$jobnr[$i]', brief='$brief[$i]' , detail='$detail[$i]' , expectation='$expectation[$i]', overall_result='$overall_result[$i]' , comments='$comments[$i]', status='$status[$i]', country='$country[$i]' , type='$type[$i]' , week='$week[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'";
$query4=mysql_query("UPDATE kpi_ytd SET person='$person[$i]', jobnr='$jobnr[$i]', brief='$brief[$i]' , detail='$detail[$i]' , expectation='$expectation[$i]', overall_result='$overall_result[$i]' , comments='$comments[$i]', status='$status[$i]', country='$country[$i]' , type='$type[$i]' , week='$week[$i]' WHERE id='$id[$i]'");
$query5=mysql_query("insert into kpi_records values('','$person[$i]','$jobnr[$i]','$week[$i]','$brief[$i]','$detail[$i]','$expectation[$i]','$overall_result[$i]','$comments[$i]', '$status[$i]', '$country[$i]', '$type[$i]')");
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);
}
}
if(isset($result1)){
echo("<h3>Please Wait,<br>Updating Branch Tasks...</h3><script>location.href = '/list.php';</script>");
}
?>
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and are simply ASSUMING your queries should be working. BAD assumption. Never assume success. always check for failure: `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: what errors do you see if any? If none, try turning on `error_reporting`

Comment: are you changing your username and password to your server's credentials when uploading to your server?

Comment: Is the host, username and password really correct on the live FTP?

Comment: @CodeGodie , I turned on the error reporting and got the following: "Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home/.../public_html/team/myfile.php". I also, checked and double checked my username and password to the server and everything is in order there.

Comment: What did you get? I dont see it. Remember, you can edit your original post and add any extra things like the errors

Comment: yes that warning is telling you that you should not be using `mysql`, rather use `mysqli` since `mysql` is deprecated and will no longer be supported in the next PHP version. If you want I can help through Teamviewer, let me know

Comment: @CodeGodie , would really only be that?, I would really appreciate it if you can help through teamviewer.

Answer (score 0):

if you can make sure your configuration host, user and password database on online server is right.

then from what i read, you must try change your code "mysql_" to "mysqli_"

example :

```
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
```

to

```
mysqli_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
```

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_mysqli.asp

my answer will change depends on your comments, cause i don't know your stuff there.